# Are we going to allow monetary appreciation questions for rare manga books and merchandise?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

This question got posted: [What are the value of these Trigun books?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/42876/what-are-the-value-of-these-trigun-books)

And I'd like to ask the site users: Do you think it's a good idea to allow these kinds of questions on our site? Or do you think we should redirect people to specialized forums and remove such questions?

I don't think any StackExchange site openly supports evaluating how much a rare comic book, piece of merchandise, hardware or coins could be worth to collectors. Is it a good thing or a bad thing? What do you think it would bring to the site in terms of informational value?

Comment: Might be worthwhile to point out that besides the mentioned question, there only seems to be [one other](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/how-much-is-guyver-manga-video-collection-worth) such question at the time.

Comment: This seems like a skillset that we collectively do not possess, and are unlikely to ever possess. I suppose if somebody wanted to know what the retail price of a piece of merchandise is, that would be fine (albeit uninteresting). But appraisals? We probably shouldn't have those.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. On one hand, I believe it's possible to do appraisal by comparing to old-book shop/auction price *if the product is clear* (e.g. the Guyver collection is clear, but the Trigun doujinshi **is not identified yet, making another problem**). But on the other hand, I can't see it being useful in the long run if we're going to follow SE's mission, to build a quality knowledge repository, not to be a personal helpdesk...

Answer (score 5):

**Are we going to allow monetary appreciation questions for rare manga books and merchandise?**

I would say no, as [aki tanaka](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2516/aki-tanaka) mentions in the comments.

> I can't see it being useful in the long run if we're going to follow SE's mission, to build a quality knowledge repository, not to be a personal helpdesk

The answers would most likely only be tailored I to the asker, and nobody else.

<strike>I also doubt the regular Anime & Manga fan has any knowledge of (rare) manga books, besides the info a simple google would provide.</strike>

**do you think we should redirect people to specialized forums and remove such questions?**

I would suggest we close the questions as **off-topic** and invite them to join us in chat.

In the chat, somebody might be able to identify the price, or point people in the right direction.

Comment: While some information can be gotten via Google, there are almost always better sources for this. Yahoo Auctions has a closed auction search which is pretty useful. Suruga-ya and Mandarake (and maybe others) advertise the prices they will pay for most merchandise in their database even if they don't have it in stock, and they tend to be about half of the sale prices on average. There are plenty of other sources too. For much rarer items it may be hard to put a price on, but for 99% of things I think we can at least give a rough estimate backed by objective evidence.

Comment: Additionally, while any individual member may not be knowledgeable about a large amount of merchandise, as a whole we may have a fair bit of expertise among us (for example, I can pretty confidently estimate the value of any idolm@ster merchandise to within a factor of 2 if not better). The point being, I don't agree with your claim that we can not do better than Google can on questions of this type. I don't have a strong opinion on the other arguments though right now.

Comment: @LoganM And that is precisely the reason we should invite them to the chat instead, as people such as yourself still might be able to help them. However, lack of knowledge shouldn't necessarily be a reason for not accepting the questions, hence I scrapped that statement.